# Adding exception in Python-Abaqus if operation happens to fail

Tags: python, exception, abaqus

I am trying to add some exceptions to my Python code when running the "InstanceFromBooleanCut" operation in Abaqus. Basically I am cutting a series of parts  and I do not want my script to stop if the operations happens to fail.
Say that I have a part called "pr1" (my cutting instance) and I want to use it to cut parts "pr2", "pr3" and "pr4".
Let's assume that the operation will be successful for the cut with pr2 and pr4 but will fail for pr3.

I have tried using a "try-except" in my code but it doesn't do what I want. Basically it cuts pr1 and pr2 successfully, then fails when cutting pr1 and pr3 and the process breaks here and it never tries to perform the cut operation for pr1 and pr4.

How could I fix this?

Thank you very much!

My code:

```
pr1 = model.parts['Part-1-r']
pr2 = model.parts['Part-2-r']
pr3 = model.parts['Part-3-r']
pr4 = model.parts['Part-4-r']

#Try to cut pr2 using pr1 (success)
try:
    cut12=assy.InstanceFromBooleanCut(cuttingInstances=(assy.instances['Part-1-r'], ), instanceToBeCut=assy.instances['Part-2-r'], name='Part-1-2', originalInstances=SUPPRESS)
except ValueError:
    print "Oops! Not good" #we should not get here

#Try to cut pr3 using pr1 (cut operation fails)
try:
    cut13=assy.InstanceFromBooleanCut(cuttingInstances=(assy.instances['Part-1-r'], ), instanceToBeCut=assy.instances['Part-3-r'], name='Part-1-3', originalInstances=SUPPRESS)
except ValueError:
    print "Oops! Not good" # in this example an exception must show up

#Try to cut pr4 using pr1 (not happening at the moment due to the previous failed operation)
try:
    cut14=assy.InstanceFromBooleanCut(cuttingInstances=(assy.instances['Part-1-r'], ), instanceToBeCut=assy.instances['Part-4-r'], name='Part-1-4', originalInstances=SUPPRESS)
except ValueError:
    print "Oops! Not good" #we should not get here
```

Comment: what does it do? ie. error message, crash?  Not sure off hand if you can still use instance `Part-1-r` for cutting after you SUPPRESSED it the first time.  Try turning off the `originalInstances=SUPPRESSED`  and explicitly deleting the instances you are done with.

Comment: I have managed to fix it by simply changing the type of exception to "except AbaqusException, message:". Thanks!

Comment: Please consider adding your comment as an answer for future reference